# Recargar componente hijo ante un evento. Angular7

Tags: angular

Estoy usando angular 7 y tengo un componente en el que defino un array y se lo paso a otro componente por su selector

```
<app-personas-Lista
  *ngIf="show == true"
  [miArray]="personas-Lista"
></app-personaR>
```

Cuando pasa determinado evento, ese array cambia sus valores y quiero recargar ese componente hijo para que muestres los nuevos valores, cómo puedo hacerlo?

Agrego detalle del código, acción que modifica el array en el componente padre:

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  name: FormControl;
  show: boolean;
 personas-Lista: Historic[];
  
  constructor(private service: Reportservice) {
    this.name = new FormControl('', []);
    this.show = true;
    this.personas-Lista= [];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
 actionSearch() {
    this.show = false;
    this.service
  .getHistoryByUsername(this.name.value)
  .subscribe((history) => {
    this.personas-Lista.splice(0,this.personas-Lista.length);
    personas-Lista.forEach(h => this.personas-Lista.push(h));
  });
   this.show = true;
  }
```

Luego en el componente hijo:

```
@Input() miArray: Historic[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Historic>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'ID',
    'Asignado a',
  ];
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.miArray);
  }
  ngOnChanges(){
    this.ngOnInit();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, puedes compartir mas a detalle tu código, para conocer el motivo del por que no te esta actualizando, teóricamente angular debería de actualizar automáticamente el componente debido a que es  un data-binding.

Comment: Listo @OscarLudick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes implementar el ngOnChanges de forma correcta. Además, llamar a ngOnInit dentro del scope de otro hook no es muy buena práctica, ya que es parte del core de Angular y está destinado a ser manipulado por el mismísimo Angular... puedes tener errores inesperados en tu aplicación.

Prueba esto en el componente hijo:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  changes.miArray && this.miArray = changes.miArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema consiste en que el evento `ngOnChanges` no se esta mandando llamar, esto se debe a que tu arreglo **personas-Lista** esta apuntando siempre a la misma referencia incluso si lo modificas (agregar, eliminar, etc). Dado a que la referencia siempre apunta al mismo arreglo necesitas crear uno nuevo, tienes muchas opciones, lo mas simple sería que reasignes una copia de tu arreglo ya construido:

```
this.personas-Lista = [...this.personas-Lista];
```